# Difference between “Erinnerung” and “Gedächtnis”

Tags: difference

Both Erinnerung and Gedächtnis can be translated into English as "memory". Are there instances where you would use one word and not the other?

Comment: It is always interesting, how the reference language influences the perception of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "die Erinnerung" and "das Gedächtnis" can be used to express "in memory of somebody/something":

> In Erinnerung an die Schlacht von ...
>
> Im Gedenken an unseren Großvater ...

The second sounds a bit more formal, but otherwise their meaning is rather the same.

"Das Gedächtnis" can also be used to express "the memory":

> Sein Gedächtnis ist nicht mehr das beste, er hat Anzeichen von Alzheimer.

Here, "Erinnerung" would not fit well.

Comment: in the last example, you could replace *Gedächtnis* with *Erinnerungsvermögen*

Comment: furthermore: *"Die Erinerrung"* is the memory of a single "happening" and *"Das Gedächtnis"* is the place where all the memories are "stored"

Comment: @Vogel612 's comment is the actual answer imo. There is one notable exception though: in  the bible text "tut dies zu meinem Gedächtnis" (Do this in remembrance of me), "Gedächtnis" ist used to mean "Gedenken" or "Erinnerung".

Comment: This is mixing up _das Gedenken_ with _das Gedächtnis_, which makes it quite confusing. Hence I give -1 here.

Answer (score 3):

- **Gedächtnis**
  is the container
- **Erinnerung**
  is the content

---

If you talk about **Gedächtnis,** you talk about the container in which memories are stored:

> Egon hat ein **Gedächtnis** wie ein Elefant.
> <sup>Egon has a **memory** like an elephant.</sup>
> Das **Gedächtnis** von Sandra ist wie ein Nudelsieb, alles rutscht durch, sie vergisst alles.
> <sup>Sandra's **memory** is like a noodle sieve, everything slips through, she forgets everything.</sup>
> Sabine hat ein fotographisches **Gedächtnis,** sie kann sich an jedes Detail erinnern.
> <sup>Sabine has a photographic **memory,** she can remember every detail.</sup>
> Das **Gedächtnis** von Manfred funktioniert nicht mehr richtig, er ist dement.
> <sup>Manfred's **memory** no longer works properly, he is demented.</sup>

If you talk about **Erinnerung** you talk about events, pictures, sounds, smells etc. that are stored in your *Gedächtnis.*

> Hans und Lisa verbindet die **Erinnerung** an den ersten Kuss.
> <sup>Hans and Lisa are united by the **memory** of their first kiss.</sup>
> Oskar blätterte das Fotoalbum durch und schwelgte in **Erinnerungen.**
> <sup>Oskar flipped through the photo album and wallowed in **memories.**</sup>
> Die **Erinnerung** an den Anschlag ruft bei vielen Wut und Trauer hervor.
> <sup>The **memory** of the attack evokes anger and sadness in many.</sup>